# How do I get plot_geoms() to work in python?

Tags: python, package

So I am running a block of code that contains:

```
from plot_geoms import *
```

which returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'plot_geoms'
```

now, doing

```
$ pip install plot_geoms
```

(in ubuntu) returns:

```
Collecting plot-geoms
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plot-geoms (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for plot-geoms
```

Is this the correct way to get package `plot-geoms`? Is `plot-geoms` even a package?

---

as far as I know, this is called latter in the code, as in:

```
plot_geom(object_1, color='red', linewidth=3) 
plot_geom(object_2, color='green', linewidth=3)
```

Comment: and the part of your code where plot_geoms is being used, would be nice.

Comment: `plot_geom(object_1, color='red', linewidth=3)` and 
`plot_geom(object_2, color='green', linewidth=3)` for example (I know, it is without a final 's' now)

Comment: @user189035 It looks like a package but it may not be in PyPI repository, so you might not be able to install it using pip.

Comment: Ok, but would you know how to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot_geoms` is not a package. Think your searching after ggplot.

```
pip install ggplot
```

I assuming you try to use the http://aonghuslawlor.com/blog/zalando-challenge.html example. Don't know where he got the plot_geoms. But you can just try to replace the code with the corresponding ggplot code.

Comment: I still get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'plot_geoms'` when typping `from plot_geoms import *` --do I need to replace that last line by `from ggplot import *`?

Comment: Cause plot_geoms is not a package. From where do you have your code, or code you just show me your code?

Comment: @Kordi What does your answer exactly do?